# How do I remove javax.* from system classes

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, classpath, classloader

I am using Jetty, and configure each web application using WebAppContext. I want to remove all javax.* classes from the System classes in order for the class loader to load the classes from WEB-INF/lib rather than the system classloader.

Comment: What specifically are you attempting to do?  As this is a recipe for bigger and more difficult issues to troubleshoot.  It seems as if you have a specific artifact that you want to use from your WebAppContext, lets focus on that specific one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have managed to remove javax.* classes from system classes following the instructions from here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/Jetty_Classloading